# Monitor and record ethernet port upload speeds

Tags: programming, data-acquisition

Can I use Mathematica to monitor and record ethernet port upload speeds?

I briefly looked at `DeviceStream`; not sure if that can be made to work or if that's the best place to start.

I used some (not cheap) video equipment to screen record my FTP upload progress. If there is a way to have Mathematica (or preferably a CDF document) monitor and record upload speeds, that would be useful.  Or if this is something Linux can handle, I'm open to going that route.